# code formatting in VS and command line

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, code-formatting

I need a tool that would allow developers to format code using Visual Studio and also check if this formatting was applied from command line (for using in pre commit hook, CI builds, etc.) I am totally fine with default VS formatting or ReSharper formatting or any other sane default, but I need support from both VS and command line for the same style. Right now some developers use ReSharper, some use plain VS and 10s of lines of code get moved right or left with every commit with no actual change whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I once heard about on a conference, but did not use it myself, because I usually do solo. Take a look at [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/)